# How do I remove duplicates in mongodb based on multiple fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here's an example of my docs:

```
[{name:"duplicate", value:true, id:2910921},{name:"duplicate", value:true, id:32838293},{name:"duplicate", value:false, id:3283232},{name:"notDuplicate", value:true, id:382932}]
```

I want to remove if there are multiple documents that contain the same name **and** the same value. In the example above it would remove one document, either `{name:"duplicate", value:true, id:2910921}` or `{name:"duplicate", value:true, id:32838293}`, it does't matter to me which one.

So far, I've considered just creating a new field for each of these which would be something like newField: "duplicatetrue" and then I could just use distinct on these to remove dupes, but I am having trouble figuring out how to concat two different fields with different types into a new field. I'm definitely open to better suggestions as well. Here's what I have so far:

```
db.collection(collectionName).updateMany({}, {$set: {"newField": ["$name","$value"]  }})
```

However, the above line doesn't output the values, rather it outputs exactly newField: ["$name","$value"]

Removing the quotes from $name and $value does not work either.

I'm using the Node mongodb driver: 3.5.8

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: @whoami mongodb driver: 3.5.8: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb, is that what you mean?

Comment: nope that's the node.js driver which you're using to connect to MongoDB server, I'm asking about MongoDB server version..

Comment: mongod --version outputs: v4.2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in two ways

1. **In one DB call :** Using aggregation operator [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html), Maybe you can also use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) but which is not much useful for your case.
2. **In two DB calls :** As if you think `$out` is destructive and with millions of documents in collection can be an issue in production environment, then you can first read all the `_id`'s of documents to be deleted & use [.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteMany/index.html) to delete all docs at once. (You can use any unique identifier on a doc instead of `_id` but I've used `_id` as it's indexed by default - which can help to run `deleteMany()` quicker).

**Step 1:**

Using `$out` - So as I've said it is destructive cause it will override the entire collection if input name matches or will create a new collection by the result of your aggregation query. So test your aggregation query very well prior to using `$out` as last stage. Also write data to temporary collection & rename the collections after everything is good enough. Consider a down-time while renaming collections

*Query :*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: { _id: { name: "$name", value: "$value" },
      doc: { $last: "$$ROOT" } // Retrieve only last doc in a group
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$doc" } // replace doc as object as new root of document
  },
  { $out : 'collection_new' } // Test above aggregation & then use this 
])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Y7tguMv73c)

**Step 2:**

1. Using an aggregation query you'll get list of `_ids` to be deleted from collection.

*Query :*

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    /**
     * Group on matching docs :
     * { name: "duplicate", value: false}, 
     * { name: "duplicate", value: true}, 
     * { name: "duplicate-yes", value: true},
     * { name: "notDuplicate", value: true} 
     * */
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { name: "$name", value: "$value" },
        _idsNeedsToBeDeleted: { $push: "$$ROOT._id" } // push all `_id`'s to an array
      }
    },
    /** Remove first element - which is removing a doc */
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        _idsNeedsToBeDeleted: { $slice: [ "$_idsNeedsToBeDeleted", 1, { $size: "$_idsNeedsToBeDeleted" } ] }
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$_idsNeedsToBeDeleted" // Unwind `_idsNeedsToBeDeleted`
    },
    /** Group without a condition & push all `_idsNeedsToBeDeleted` fields to an array */
    {
      $group: { _id: "", _idsNeedsToBeDeleted: { $push: "$_idsNeedsToBeDeleted" } }
    },
    {$project : { _id : 0 }} // Optional stage
     /** At the end you'll have an [{ _idsNeedsToBeDeleted: [_ids] }] or [] */
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZWpPb96kEPi)

2. Now using `.deleteMany()` - delete all docs :

*Query :*

```
db.collection.deleteMany( { "_id" : {$in : [_ids]} } );
```

Consideration prior to `.deleteMany()` you need to check aggregation result is not an empty array `[]` & has a doc with `_idsNeedsToBeDeleted` field which is an array. Also since we're matching against `_id` in DB - aggregations `_idsNeedsToBeDeleted` array will be an array of strings - So iterate over array, convert string to `ObjectId()` & use that array of `ObjectId()`'s in delete query.

**Note :**

Irrespective of what step you choose - Since we're grouping on `name + value` you need to make sure all of your docs has those fields.

Comment: thank you, I appreciate the extra notes on why I'd choose on of the methods of the other and the comments explaining each step within aggregation, mucho helpful.

Comment: also, thanks for the introduction to mongoplayground, this is the simple tool I never knew I needed to test pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about mongo but using the node you can remove duplicates. i tried this method for one of requirement that worked fine. please try this by chagning as you need var names.

```
function arrUnique(arr) {
    var cleaned = [];
    arr.forEach(function(itm) {
        var unique = true;
        cleaned.forEach(function(itm2) {
            if (_.isEqual(itm, itm2)) unique = false;
        });
        if (unique)  cleaned.push(itm);
    });
    return cleaned;
}

var newField = arrUnique(newField);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you 100% put me in the right direction by doing this in node and with the use of a foreach, unfortunately, your function didn't work perfectly for me since it seems like it requires lodash(?) and I believe its returned an array of unique values rather than all of the different values that I could delete from the collection.

Comment: yah its my pleasure to here its gave u idea. if you got help from this give a upvote too;-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it natively in node seemed to do the trick (probably not the fastest or most efficient way but the following worked):

```
const array = await db.collection(collectionName).find({}).toArray();
const newArr = array.map((item) => {
  const newObj = Object.assign({}, item, {
    hiWorld: `${item.name}${item.amount}`,
  });
  return newObj;
});
var uniqueItems = [];
var duplicateIds = [];
newArr.forEach((item) => {
  if (uniqueItems.includes(item.hiWorld)) {
    duplicateIds.push(item._id);
  } else {
    uniqueItems.push(item.hiWorld);
  }
});

await db.collection(collectionName).deleteMany({ _id: { $in: duplicateIds } });
```

Comment: You can try aggregation to get `duplicateIds` instead of reading all the docs to code :-) Even if you've to just use `projection` to read only certain needed fields..